# Microsoft Word 2007: Caption with many pages in Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I was wondering if it is possible to have a caption with more than one page in the table of contents for Microsoft Word 2007.

For instance, let's say I have "Equation 1. Linear Model" on page 5 and "Equation 1. Linear Model" on page 44 (the same equation would be on both these pages). How do I make it so that in the table of contents under list of equations it shows:
"Equation 1. Linear Model............5, 44"

I have already tried making the same caption but that creates a new entry like this:
"Equation 1. Linear Model.............5"
"Equation 2. Linear Model.............44"

And I have tried the cross-reference function but that didn't work either.

If anyone can help me out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You are describing an index as opposed to a table of contents. Do you know the difference (might an index suit your needs better?)

Comment: I meant "Table of Equations", which you create under "Insert Table of Figures" under Word 2007. I do know the differences and I need to have a "Table of Equations" as part of the template I am using.